# Windows Authentication to Oracle for domain group

Tags: windows, oracle, authentication

I know that it is possible to use "OS authentication" to authenticate Windows users in Oracle database. The process is basically passing current Windows user id to Oracle for authentication.

The question is - is it possible to authenticate domain group in Oracle (as it is possible with SQL Server integrated security), so that there would be no need to create separate database user for each domain member?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Oracle has a [whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/wp/Oracle_with_Active_Directory_TWP.pdf) on this, and [here's a tutorial](http://www.fm-berger.de/ora_adinteg/),

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but I would love to be proven wrong.