# Windows Domain Logins on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: windows, oracle, authentication, dns

Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1.14

I currently have an Oracle database with a user who contains a set of tables, views, etc. However, I would like this schema to be shared among multiple people with different logins.

My company has a domain and each employee logs into their computers through this domain, for example

COMPANY_NAME/username

I am hoping to be able to use windows authentication to log each user into the database. This way everyone at the company will automatically have a login with a password they are used to.

In Oracle SQL Developer, I have tried ticking "OS Authentication", and received "Invalid username/password" upon testing the connection. Do I need to create an Oracle user for each domain?

I have also tried checking "Use OCI/Thick driver", but it cannot be checked unless "Use Oracle Client" is configured, which I'm also unsure about.

This question appears to be a duplicate: 
[Windows Authentication to Oracle for domain group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824139/windows-authentication-to-oracle-for-domain-group), however the tutorial link is dead. I have not been able to find another tutorial for how to set this up anywhere.

Comment: SQL Developer's help topic on OS connections refers to this document, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/clntsec.htm.  There is a section titled, "Support for OS Authentication" and it has a Windows section titled,"Configuration Steps for Windows",

Answer (score 2):

There is a server-side parameter called `os_authent_prefix` that is typically set to `OPS$`, and the network user id needs to be prefixed with this in addition to having the `IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY` option added to the `create user` statement.

So if your Windows account id is `hambone,` then your OS-authentication login would be `OPS$hambone`, and you don't need a password.  I used it for years, and it never required the domain to be specified for a Windows account, which was nice because it meant the same credentials worked for my Unix account.

SQL*Plus, for example would look like:

```
sqlplus OPS$hambone/@myserver
```

Likewise, connection strings for applications just have nothing for the password.

For Toad, you would put `OPS$hambone` as userid and leave the password blank.  SQL Developer, I'm honestly not sure -- I can't stand it; I use PL/SQL Developer, but with the various options they have I'd imagine you select OS authentication and/or put the `OPS$hambone`.

Read the caveats/security warnings on OS authentication.  I think in a private network the risks are outweighed by the advantages, but that's for you to decide.